# Flask module not found in apache server

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm running the whole tutorial from (https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/) and I have encountered into the following issues. I'm currently running the apache2 server and this is the error log.

```
[Wed Feb 15 16:57:45.115664 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29447:tid 140623447664384] [remote 182.55.172.115:9328] mod_wsgi (pid=29447): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Feb 15 16:57:45.115711 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29447:tid 140623447664384] [remote 182.55.172.115:9328] mod_wsgi (pid=29447): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Wed Feb 15 16:57:45.115730 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29447:tid 140623447664384] [remote 182.55.172.115:9328] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Feb 15 16:57:45.115749 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29447:tid 140623447664384] [remote 182.55.172.115:9328]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Feb 15 16:57:45.115799 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29447:tid 140623447664384] [remote 182.55.172.115:9328]     from FlaskApp import app as application
[Wed Feb 15 16:57:45.115819 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29447:tid 140623447664384] [remote 182.55.172.115:9328] ImportError: No module named FlaskApp
```

My config file is as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                ServerAdmin Admin@server.com
                WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-path=/var/www/FlaskApp:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
                WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My Flask app wsgi file as below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import sys
import os, sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp")

activate_this = '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))


from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'gfuaskdf24432giafsd23khk'
```

And my _init_.py as below

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Hi there, how ya doin?"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Pretty sure the issue isn't on *init*.py but probably on either the wsgi file or on the virtual machine. I've tried many ways but to no avail (but I could be doing it wrong too).

Need help from the community.

Comment: What is the full path name for the ``FlaskApp/__init__.py`` file? Are your directories/files accessible to the Apache user? Unrelated, but also refer to http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for best practices of setting up Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi. Don't use ``python-path`` to refer to the Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure your init file is named `__init__.py` ? I see you reference it in your question as `init.py`. That could be the issue the `__init__.py` shows python it is part of a package and when you import other packages it will look at that file first. If you didn't name it properly perhaps that is why its saying it can't find the module you need?

Comment: Yes I did rename the file name as _init_.py, apologize for the typo.

Comment: Ah yea i think stackoverflow formatting makes it tricky that's why i surrounded mine in backticks to make it like a code snippet. Also in your wsgi file have you tried importing your app like this `from . import app as application`

Comment: yeah I did and this is what I put at the end of the wsgi file - 

"from FlaskApp import app as application"

. Couldn't figure out what the problem is

Comment: In the tutorial example there is a trailing slash on the sys.path you could try that `sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")` I'm not sure if your changes to activate a virtual environment are effecting it somehow.

It keeps mentioning that import line isn't working so I'd try a couple of things just to make sure, maybe you didn't get the directory structure the same you should try `from .FlaskApp import app as application` or `from . import app as application` as there are a couple of dirs named FlaskApp here

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked too long ago. But, nowadays, if you are not using a python virtual environment, you can face this problem too:

I am using APACHE2 - mod_wsgi. For production purposes. My OS: Linux / Ubuntu.

I am not using a virtual environment just because no other project will be used on the server. So, it s not necessary.

Right after configuring everything, I got this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (unknown location)

In the resume, www-data cannot import 'Flask'. It´s not a `flask`, but `Flask`.

My tip for you:

a) Behaves as www-data user to get the right view. And do like this:

```
su -s /bin/bash www-data
```

Now, your prompt has changed for www-data.

Next step:

b) Acting as www-data, parse this:

```
python3 -c "from flask import Flask;"
```

You will see the same message inside /var/log/apache2/error.log

How to solve this without searching around as crazy, changing code, etc...

c) Give read permission to the user `www-data` read Python3´s dist-packages folder, like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/
sudo chmod -R u+r /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/
```

d) Now, just repeat item `b` and that error just gone! Restart apache2, refresh the page!

Be happy!